# Temporarily prime dns with known ip address

Tags: domain-name-system

I've recently registered a domain and configured all the nameservers. However it takes some time for the dns to propagate. Is there a way temporarily prime the dns resolution on osx with the correct IP address for the domain until the primary dns network is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess on osx you can use the "/etc/hosts" file like any other unix.

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
8.8.8.8       google-public-dns-a.google.com
<ip address>  <your new domain>
```

It should work until your domain is known by your dns.

Answer (score 5):

DNS records don't propagate. If you've set up the name servers and set up the DNS records then it should work immediately. The only issue is if your name servers can't be located or resolved.

Comment: For a more thorough discussion also see joeqwerty's [answer here](http://serverfault.com/questions/153690/why-arent-our-dns-records-propagating-out-into-the-internet/153723#153723).