# How to map a domain name to a load balancer in google cloud platform?

Tags: load-balancing, subdomain, domain-name, google-cloud-platform

I have successfully set up a load balancer in google cloud platform

[image]

If I use the IP as shown in the image, I can test and verify that the set up is working as I planned.

Now I would like to map a domain name to the IP. I want to use `www.mycompany.com`. I have already created a `A` record in my DNS to point `www` to `1.2.3.4`. However the domain name gives a 404 error.

[image]

I am sure I need to associate  this new domain name to the IP address.

There is no obvious place to do it in `load balanceing` or `external IP addresses` screen.

Where can I do it?

Comment: GFE will return an default `404` page if you are trying to access your `frontend` using port you didn't assigned to it. In your case you probably trying to access `http://www.mycompany.com.` (port `80`). Instead you should access `https://www.mycompany.com.`

Answer (score 7):

It seems to take time for gcp to know how to handle the new domain name. About some 15 minutes after the additional of the new `A` record, the domain name `www.mycompany.com` starts to work. The 404 screen is gone

Comment: Since GCP is a distributed system, certainly some changes might take some time to propagate. Nevertheless, when dealing with DNS records there is also a [propagation delay](http://serverfault.com/questions/82251/why-is-it-called-dns-propagation)