# DNS naked domain not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I'm a newbie at server administration. My DNS file looks like this, WWW resolves.  http://planandshop.co.uk does not resolve. I've just added in the last entry.. waiting for propagation, but can anyone help?

```
;
; Database file planandshop.co.uk..dns for planandshop.co.uk. zone
;   Zone version:  1

planandshop.co.uk.          IN  SOA     ns2.infotipp.hu. admin.infotipp.hu. (
            2018021115  ;serial 
            86400   ;refresh 
            7200    ;retry
            3600000     ;expire
            3600 )  ;ttl

;
;       Zone NS Records
;
        www.planandshop.co.uk.          IN  A   185.40.20.167
        mail.planandshop.co.uk.         IN MX 1 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
        @                               IN MX 0 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
        ftp.planandshop.co.uk.          IN  A   185.40.20.167
        mail.planandshop.co.uk.         IN  A   185.40.20.167
        @                               IN  A   185.40.20.167
```

Comment: BTW, [DNS does not propagate](https://serverfault.com/questions/82251/why-is-it-called-dns-propagation/82288). Moreover, you don't have to wait the TTL for the caches to expire to tell whether your configuration is working or not. Simply test against your authoritative name servers, `dig planandshop.co.uk A @ns2.infotipp.hu` where the changes take effect immediately after `rndc reload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `$ORIGIN`? As `@` refers to the origin, you should have `$ORIGIN planandshop.co.uk.` if you wish to use `@`. Notice, that any of the other records aren't relative to the origin!

So, you could either have all the records as absolute:

```
www.planandshop.co.uk.  IN  A   185.40.20.167
mail.planandshop.co.uk. IN MX 1 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
planandshop.co.uk.      IN MX 0 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
ftp.planandshop.co.uk.  IN  A   185.40.20.167
mail.planandshop.co.uk. IN  A   185.40.20.167
planandshop.co.uk.      IN  A   185.40.20.167
```

Or use relative records like this:

```
$ORIGIN planandshop.co.uk.
www          IN  A   185.40.20.167
mail         IN MX 1 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
@            IN MX 0 mail.planandshop.co.uk.
ftp          IN  A   185.40.20.167
mail         IN  A   185.40.20.167
@            IN  A   185.40.20.167
```

Or any combination of the above, as long as you set the `$ORIGIN` first.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added the very top part, as I'm not sure whether I still need to use $ORIGIN?